# Stream and c++ - parsing file

Tags: c++, parsing, stream

I did it before... But I forgot.
I have a file with some data:

> 0.5 0.6 0.7
>   1.2 1.5

How can I read this in c++? I did it with stream... something like:

```
float var = 0;
stream >> var;
```

Comment: In addition to the answers below, here is a very good reference for C++, you'll find further information on streams in section 6: http://www.icce.rug.nl/documents/cplusplus/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
std::ifstream stream("C:/a.txt");
    float var = 0;
    while(stream >> var)
    {
        //Do some processing
    }
```

Comment: `eof()` returns true only after the extraction fails.

Comment: I have edited the answer to make it safe. @Ockonal: Please check the edited answer.

Answer (score 6):

The following snippet should give you a clue. Don't forget to include `<fstream>`.

```
std::ifstream fin("filename.txt");
float value;
while (fin >> value)
{
    // Do whatever you want with the value
}
```

Do not try to test `fin.eof()` it won't tell you if you're about to bump to the end of file.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. The << operator treats spaces as a separator.

```
float array[5] = {0.0f};

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    stream >> array[i];
}
```

BTW I did 5 since you had 5 in your example. (and I am assuming you have the stream setup)

Comment: @Ólafur - how is that going to work? Perhaps my C++ syntax memory is waay off, but as I read it, you're going to read from the file into the *address* of `var`, not into the next position in the array. You should want to put the `[i]` back at the end of `var`, as I had modified for you earlier - unless this is a way of using arrays I've just never seen or heard of before.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how to open a file and read data from it?

That should look something like this:

```
float var;
ifstream infile("filename");
if(infile.good()){
    while(!infile.eof()){
        infile >> var;
        cout << var << "is the next value\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: this is how I've always done file I/O; and how I've always seen it in various reference materials.

Comment: warren, your code is incorrect, see my comment at Vijay's answer (I didn't downvote, though).

Comment: eof doesn't return true until after the first failed attempt to read from the file. So (unless the file ends immediately after the last number, without a newline) your loop will perform an extra iteration.

Comment: Actually, avakar's "bumped into the end of file during the last extraction" is a better explanation than my "first failed attempt to read". If the file ends immediately after the last number, eof will turn true after the last ">>" operation that was successfull. Yes, on a lower level there was a byte-read that failed involved, but the ">>" operation was successful in that case, so "bumped into" is much better pedagogically.

Comment: @avakar - don't see an answer from Vijay. @Thomas - that's what the `.good()` call is supposed to do, I thought - make sure the file is healthy before continuing? I don't mind being wrong, but I'm a little concerned that this is how every reference manual and teacher I've ever seen has done it, and how I've been doing it for ~15 years, and it's not right :-\

Comment: The other answer was deleted. The call to good just checks that the file could be opened, and doesn't help for the problem with the loop. And yes, this is a horribly common error. (So don't delete your answer, you too! It, and the discussion, is needed as a warning.)

Answer (score 0):

To read from files, use std::ifstream.